# ¿ Cómo implementar sonidos superpuestos usando el módulo pygame de Python?

Tags: python, pygame, sonido

Estoy realizando un juego de separación de silabas, puse un sonido para cuando la palabra da error y para cuando es acertada, y para al final agregue un sonido de queda poco tiempo a partir de 15 minutos. El problema es que solo se escucha el tiempo y cuando seguis poniendo palabras no se escucha el sonido de si esta correcto o incorrecto. Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma o alguna función que me permita superponer todos estos sonidos.

Estoy usando los siguientes métodos implementados en el módulo PyGame:

```
Pygame.mixer.Sound()
Pygame.mixer.Sound.play()
```

Comment: Las preguntas así sin código no sé como responderlas, porque hay que adivinar que has intentado así que iré por lo fácil, al sonido de tiempo ejecutalo así: mixer.music.load("sonido_tiempo.wav") mixer.music.play(-1) y a los otros sin el valor de -1

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

En PyGame no es posible usar mas de un stream de música pero podrías usar dos sonidos en simultáneo:

```
sound_1, sound_2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound_1'),  pygame.mixer.Sound('sound_2')
sound_1.play()
sound_2.play()
```

De esta manera una vez que alguien acierta o desacierta una palabra volvería a sonar la música que mencionas cuando restan 15 minutos.

Answer (score 1):

En python eso se consigue implementando paralelismo (hilos) utilizando la librería `Thread` de el módulo `threading`. Puedes hacer una inmersión profunda en este módulo en [este enlace](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/threading.html). Nos serviremos también de la librería de procesamiento de audio `mutagen` para poder extraer el tiempo de duración del audio a reproducir de una manera muy fácil. Esta variable de tiempo de duración es muy importante, puesto que se precisa establecer un timer (`time.sleep()`) de espera para dar tiempo a que el archivo de audio se pueda reproducir en paralelismo, de lo contrario no lo escucharemos, aunque sí se ejecute el hilo que conecta la función que procesa la reproducción del archivo de sonido.

Te dejo un ejemplo práctico de tres sonidos (puedes poner cuantos quieras) sonando al mismo tiempo:
`
# sonar_x_3.py
# python

```
from threading import Thread
import pygame, mutagen, time

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

sound      = dict()
sound[1]   = pygame.mixer.Sound('s1.mp3')
sound[2]   = pygame.mixer.Sound('s2.mp3')
sound[3]   = pygame.mixer.Sound('s3.mp3')

def play(s):
    # Extraer la duración del archivo de audio en minutos y segundos
    min, seg = divmod(mutagen.File(f's{s}.mp3').info.length, 60)
    3
    # Sumar todos los segundos
    ts = (round(min)*60)+round(seg, 1)
    sound[s].play()

    # IMPORTANTE: si no se define este timer de espera
    # no habrá tiempo para que se reproduzca el audio
    time.sleep(ts)

Thread(target=play, args=(1,)).start()
Thread(target=play, args=(2,)).start()
Thread(target=play, args=(3,)).start()
```

`